# salt in every password yii

Tags: yii, passwords, salt

I have a table column called salt and it is a required field but I don't want to users to input their own salts
is there a way for our system to generate a salt for each password which are encrypted via sha1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Yii, so lets do this in **YII style**

I use

`Yii::app()->securityManager->generateRandomString($length,true)`

To learn about it click [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSecurityManager#generateRandomString-detail)

Comment: I would like to try this, but where exactly do you place it? in the controller? I'm very sorry for my lack of knowledge, I just started yii

Comment: I have a helper class where I have this function to generate randomstring. You can place it in components

Answer (score 1):

The Yii framework offers a class [CPasswordHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper), which generates safe BCrypt hashes with an included salt per password. With this class you can do without a separate field for the salt. An example from the Yii docu:

```
$hash = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);

if (CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($password, $hash))
    // password is good
else
    // password is bad
```

Comment: the problem is already solved sir, but i appreciate this, it really was easier this way

Comment: @shychotc - Good to hear that you could solve your problem. Please note that SHA-* is not appropriate to hash passwords, because it is designed to be fast, and therefore can be brute-forced too easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random value for each entry as a salt. It doesn't matter what the value is as long as it looks random.

Check this link : 
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: can you please give an example of the code for generating a random value in salt?

Comment: Please check this answer.http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8015/what-should-be-used-as-a-salt

Answer (score 0):

Use simplest encrypt & decrypt info in PHP

```
$salt ='whatever_you_want';
function simple_encrypt($text)
{
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
function simple_decrypt($text)
{
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

Comment: Passwords should not be stored in an encrypted format, instead one should use a one way hash function. BTW the ECB mode won't accept an IV vector, you probably get an IV of length 0.